# Find the size of 1 pixel in my CMOS camera

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a small problem with finding the pixel size of an image. I am to find size of nano and micro particles on my BW image. I used regionprops to get the area - then the diameter. Now i know the value in pixels. How do i convert to micro or nano meter scale? Do I take into account the sensor size(6.5umx6.5um) of my camera? 
I use MATLAB for image processing.

Thank you

Comment: You might also need to take the lens in account for your calculation

Comment: U mean the magnification? IF so whats the formula using the magnification to find size? I only need the image diameter not the actual, i have equations for that.

Comment: magnification = size of image / size of object.

Comment: @nkjt How do i find the size of image? I knw in pixels. How to convert?

Answer (score 0):

there is a function called `imfinfo` which will return a struct. In this struct you will maybe find three fields (it depends on the coder that you used for the image format) called `XResolution`, `YResolution` and `ResolutionUnit`. Using this 3 fields you can easily get pixel size, for example if `XResolution=10`, `YResolution=10` and `ResolutionUnit='meter'` then you have a 100cm2 pixels (its a bit unreal i know :))

I hope this helps and that your image file contains the `XResolution` and `YResolution` information in your header.

Comment: Hi, Thsnks for reply. I managed to find those but then how do i calculate pixel size? I have 72 x 72 and unit is inch. It gives absurd values in mm.

Comment: the pixel size is for example: xPixSize =  ResolutionUnit / XResolution. I agree with you that the resolution you are getting is ridiculous, but I don't know how the encoder (or your camera) works in detail... I cannot help you with that. If the answer was useful please note it +1 or accept it as a correct answer :)